# maxScroll in javascript ends in different position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have used Javascript to end the carousel at `maxScroll` and so made the scroll right button disappear at `maxScroll`. The problem is that it disappears when all the slides are empty and there remains nothing inside the container.

I would be grateful if you could show me how to fix the Javascript and hide the scroll right button when it reaches the maximum number of slides.

Also, the transition of the first element on scrolling is not smooth.

```js
let currentScrollPosition = 0;
let scrollAmount = 320;

const sCont = document.querySelector(".card-container");
const hScroll = document.querySelector(".horizontal-scroll");

const btnScrollLeft = document.querySelector("#btn-scroll-left");
const btnScrollRight = document.querySelector("#btn-scroll-right");

btnScrollLeft.style.opacity = "0";

let maxScroll = -(sCont.offsetWidth + hScroll.offsetWidth);

function scrollHorizontally(val) {
  currentScrollPosition += val * scrollAmount;
  if (currentScrollPosition > 0) {
    currentScrollPosition = 0
    btnScrollLeft.style.opacity = "0";
  } else {
    btnScrollLeft.style.opacity = "1";
  }
  if (currentScrollPosition <= maxScroll) {
    currentScrollPosition = maxScroll;
    btnScrollRight.style.opacity = "0";
  } else {
    btnScrollRight.style.opacity = "1";
  }
  sCont.style.left = currentScrollPosition + "px";
}
```

```css
.horizontal-scroll {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  position: absolute;
  gap: 10px;
  transition: 1s all ease-out;
}

.card-container .card {
  min-width: 280px;
  flex: 1;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  background: #00F260;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #0575E6, #00F260);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0575E6, #00F260);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card-container .card img {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
  height: 180px;
}


/* btn */

.horizontal-scroll .btn-scroll {
  background: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #007bff;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}

.horizontal-scroll .btn-scroll:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.horizontal-scroll .btn-scroll:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.horizontal-scroll #btn-scroll-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(200px/2);
}

.horizontal-scroll #btn-scroll-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: calc(200px/2);
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-scroll">
  <button class="btn-scroll" id="btn-scroll-left" onclick="scrollHorizontally(1)">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn-scroll" id="btn-scroll-right" onclick="scrollHorizontally(-1)">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">Card 1</div>
    <div class="card">Card 2</div>
    <div class="card">Card 3</div>
    <div class="card">Card 4</div>
    <div class="card">Card 5</div>
    <div class="card">Card 1</div>
    <div class="card">Card 2</div>
    <div class="card">Card 3</div>
    <div class="card">Card 4</div>
    <div class="card">Card 5</div>
  </div>
  <!--card-container-->
</div>
<!--horizontal-scroll-->
```

https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/YzeRRrm

Comment: The left and right buttons don't appear to be visible at all in your example?

Comment: Your maxScroll variable is wrong. On full page on my pc, it logs ```-5004```, which is far more than even the card-container width. I suggest drawing your elements on a piece of paper, that's what I do to figure out formulas for offset/dimension calculations.

Comment: @Lalalena can you calculate the maxScroll for this and tell me? i am ready to pay a small amount for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code needs to be cleaned, but it should give you an idea. I couldn't see your buttons either, so I added some temporary styles to make them visible.

Explanation:

To find out the maximum left position of the sCont box, subtract the container box(hScroll) from it. This gives us a negative value (we want it to be negative, since the content scrolls to the left).

I decided to read the widths in the click event listener, so the code works when the window is resized too (to a degree, you might want to add a window resize function).

The card container can now only have a minimum left position of the difference between the two boxes, meaning the right edge touches the container's right edge.

Your transition wasn't smooth because `left` property wasn't initially set. Transition likes initial values, else it has to calculate. Solution: Set `left: 0;` on the transitioning element.

Also, I had to remove `width: calc(100% - 100px)` from your `.card-container` because when calculating with dimensions like these, you need the true width, and css width overrides that.

```js
    let currentScrollPosition = 0;
    let scrollAmount = 320;

    const sCont = document.querySelector(".card-container");
    const hScroll = document.querySelector(".horizontal-scroll");
    const btnScrollLeft = document.getElementById("btn-scroll-left");
    const btnScrollRight = document.getElementById("btn-scroll-right");

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // i prefer adding event listeners in javascript.
    btnScrollLeft.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      scrollHorizontally(1);
    });
    btnScrollRight.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      scrollHorizontally(-1);
    });
});

    function scrollHorizontally(val) {
      let c_width = hScroll.offsetWidth,
          box_width = sCont.offsetWidth,
          amount = val * scrollAmount,
          diff = c_width - box_width;
      // to calculate the difference, we only need to subtract width of the div containing the cards.
      currentScrollPosition = currentScrollPosition + amount;

      if (currentScrollPosition > 0) {
        // cap start
        currentScrollPosition = 0;
        btnScrollLeft.style.opacity = "0";
      } else if (currentScrollPosition < diff) {
        // cap end
        currentScrollPosition = diff;
        btnScrollRight.style.opacity = "0";
      } else {
        btnScrollLeft.style.opacity = "1";
        btnScrollRight.style.opacity = "1";
      }
      sCont.style.left = currentScrollPosition + "px";
    }
```

```css
 .horizontal-scroll {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .card-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-basis: 30%;
      position: absolute;
      gap: 10px;
      left: 0;
      transition: 1s left ease-out;
    }

    .card-container .card {
      min-width: 280px;
      flex: 1;
      height: 200px;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background: #fff;
      background: #00F260;
      /* fallback for old browsers */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #0575E6, #00F260);
      /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0575E6, #00F260);
      /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      text-align: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .card-container .card img {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      pointer-events: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
      width: 100%;
      float: none;
      display: block;
      object-fit: fill;
      height: 180px;
    }

    /* btn */

    .horizontal-scroll .btn-scroll {
      background: 0;
      border: 0;
      height:20px;
      width: 20px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      padding: 0 10px;
      z-index: 10;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 40px;
      color: #007bff;
    }

    .horizontal-scroll .btn-scroll:hover {
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #007bff;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .horizontal-scroll .btn-scroll:focus {
      outline: none;
      background-color: #007bff;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .horizontal-scroll #btn-scroll-left {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: calc(200px/2);
    }

    .horizontal-scroll #btn-scroll-right {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: calc(200px/2);
    }
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-scroll">
      <button class="btn-scroll" id="btn-scroll-left">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
      </button>
      <button class="btn-scroll" id="btn-scroll-right">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">Card 1</div>
        <div class="card">Card 2</div>
        <div class="card">Card 3</div>
        <div class="card">Card 4</div>
        <div class="card">Card 5</div>
        <div class="card">Card 1</div>
        <div class="card">Card 2</div>
        <div class="card">Card 3</div>
        <div class="card">Card 4</div>
        <div class="card">Card 5</div>
      </div>
      <!--card-container-->
    </div>
    <!--horizontal-scroll-->
```

Comment: can we minimize the card-container's size and keep the buttons outside the box?

Comment: how can we make it accesissible for touch devices